popover AP With capacitor
I've got an app wrapped  with Capacitor 6.1.1. The app is written in React and is wrapped and packaged with Capacitor.
I use the popover API that is supposed to be wildly supported by now (works well on web). But it seems that the capacitor can not handle this feature. Inside the Android studio I can't see the popup. In the tomcat logger I see this:

File: https://localhost/assets/index-u-SGcgpk.js - Line 33 - Msg: Found a 'popover' attribute. If you are testing the popover API, you must enable Experimental Web Platform Features. If not, note that custom attributes must start with 'data-': https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#custom-data-attribute. This usage will likely cause site breakage when the popover API ships: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5463833265045504.

Any idea why I get this message?

In which device and android version are you testing?

Both on my own device (POCO X6) and the default one (virtual) in the android studio. Pixel_3a_API34.

The popover was introduced in chrome/chromium 114, your system webview is probably out of date. Check for updates on Google play.
